# How can I find the distance between a point and a relation?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm writing some code for a project, and I've run into the problem where I want to determine if a point is close enough to a random relation I get. Is there a way either a) to find the exact/approximate distance, so that I can set up an inequality or b) just determine if that distance is bounded by a constant? Ideally, I'd like something a function like `dist(relation,x1,y1)`.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the distance between a point and a relation?  Do you mean the distance between the point and the set of points whose coordinates satisfy the relation?

Comment: To expand on Robert Israel's interpretation. Is the relation finite? Can you effectively generate elements of the relation? Can you effectively enumerate the relation?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, sorry for the imprecision; @HagenvonEitzen If I'm understanding your question, yes there are infinitely many points that satisfy the relation; something of the sort ```y^2+x^2=r^2``` or ```x=y^3```

Answer (score 1):

If we're given no information about the relation, this is totally impossible. There are, however, quite a few cases where we know something about the relation which gives us a method to effectively calculate $dist_{relation}(p)$, where $p$ is a point.

For example, if the $relation = \{p_1, p_2, ..., p_i\}$, then we can take the distance directly by $dist_{relation}(p) = \min\limits_{1 \leq j \leq i} ||p - p_j||$.

In many cases, if $relation = \{p(t) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, we can use the methods of calculus to minimise $||p - p(t)||$.

But the general case is totally hopeless.

Comment: In particular, in the most general case, it may happen that we do not even know if the relation is empty or if $p$ itself is in it.